# How do I prevent the browser window from jumping back to the top of the page when when I open and close my panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a website that has a persistent header, with a navigation panel that slides out of the top of the screen. It currently works by wrapping the header and navigation panel in a fixed div, and giving that div a negative top margin equal to the height of the navigation.

The HTML

```
<div class="sticky">
  <div class="above-header">
    This is the navigation panel.
  </div>

  <div class="header">
    This is a logo
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.sticky {
  height:300px;
  margin:-250px 0 0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
}

.above-header {
  height:250px;
}

.header {
  height:50px;
}

.open {
  margin:0
}
```

Then I use a tiny js/jquery script to change that margin to 0, making the navigation visible.

```
$('a.toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.sticky').hasClass('open')){  
        $('.sticky').removeClass('open');
      }
      else{
        $('.sticky').addClass('open');
      }
});
```

I've got it working fine except for one problem: if I open or close the panel, the view jumps up to the top of the page, regardless of where I've scrolled to.

I've recreated [a simplified version of the problem](http://codepen.io/jgabrielsen/pen/FBeAj) on Codepen to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

I cannot imagine why it is doing this, and my Google Fu hasn't turned up any answers. Any idea what I can do to fix this problem? Or perhaps there's a better technique for this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prevent the default action (nl navigating to your url + #)

```
$('a.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sticky').toggleClass('open');
});
```

and with the toggleClass option, you can simplify your call :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. JQuery noob, and I had no idea such an option existed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<a href="#">
```

Use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
```

Comment: Holy crap, I'm an idiot. I swear I tried a million things, and I never considered something so obvious.